# Uninstallation problem in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, windows-installer

I can't uninstall one of the programs.  It says:

```
The installation source for this product is not available. 
Verify that the source exist and that you can access it. 
C://Windows/Installer/9b0ea7.msi

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:        APPCRASH
  Application Name:          explorer.exe
  Application Version:       6.1.7600.16385
  Application Timestamp:     4a5bc60d
  Fault Module Name:         StackHash_b4ee
  Fault Module Version:      0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:    00000000
  Exception Code:            c0000005
  Exception Offset:          6fd4649e
  OS Version:                6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:                 5146
  Additional Information 1:  b4ee
  Additional Information 2:  b4ee5de6a2322745523997a782b35692
  Additional Information 3:  277e
  Additional Information 4:  277e19c30fbd5f6bb531ec9e027c37c3
```

Is there a way to uninstall it anyway? OS is Win 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with [revouninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/). That might give a better result.